# How to call the Twitter Search widget through an AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter

I would like to know how I could load live Twitter updates by using the Twitter Search Widget by an AJAX call.
The requirement is to load the Twitter Live feed by an AJAX call when the user clicks on a certain Tab. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought the search widget already has an option to poll for new results? https://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_search

Comment: Yes that option is available but the problem is how can I load the Twitter Search Widget on a certain page when a user clicks on a tab by making use of an Ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by a page refresh. Initially I was trying to do this by a AJAX call but due to a JSON call by the browser I couldn't display unique results for football and news as the results would get mixed up. Therefore with a page refresh and searching for a group of words I managed to resolve it.